# Changing variable into already existing local webpage workaround

Tags: javascript, php, html, internet-explorer, code-injection

Hello I have old NVR which has limit of characters into its password box. My problem is that I changed the default password throught admin panel which had no limitations and now I can not surpass the login becaouse of too many characters. Is there some way to force IE to remove this limit so I can  log into it? The NVR firmware also has this limitation.

The code from firefox source:

```
<div><span id='xyhm'><script>document.write(top.str_user);</script></span>
                    <input type='text' maxlength='20' id='username' value="" onKeyDown="if (event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;"></div>
                    <div><span id='xmm'><script>document.write(top.str_pwd);</script></span>
                    <input type="password" maxlength="6" id="password" onKeyDown="if (event.keyCode==13) ld();"></div>
                </div>
```

```
function ld()
{
    user = $("username").value;
    pwd = $("password").value;
    login();
}
```

```
<script>
document.write('<script src="/cgi-bin/getparam.cgi?user=admin&pwd="><\/script>');
</script>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to amend the maxlength attribute? Yeah you could remove / change that with jQuery quite easily - see the .attr() function.

Comment: Just remove the attribute using browser dev tools? (I am assuming you need this only one time, so that you can set a new, “conforming” password afterwards?)

Comment: What is that last snippet of code supposed to be? Is this system passing the login credentials via GET? Then you could probably just go and type `…/cgi-bin/getparam.cgi?user=admin&pwd=YOURPASSWORDHERE` directly into the address bar.

Comment: How about the issue? I think CBroe's comments make sense. You can open F12 dev tools to remove the `maxlength="6"` then input the password. Or put the password directly in the url parameter. If these don't work, I think you'd better change your password to meet the length requirement.